# SWIFT - CALayer between PNG and background image

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, calayer

I have seen many stackoverflow posts or tutorials on how make a mask with an image and a rectangle or a circle, but it is possible to make a mask between a png file with transparency and a background image.

[image: mask in photoshop]

In the photoshop screenshot I use the wolf png image as a mask for the background.

Any approach for this with CALayer or other in SWIFT ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

UIView as of iOS 8 has a [mask](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622557-mask) property which you can set to any view with an alpha channel, including a UIImageView that has your image in it.

This is just a wrapper arround CALayer's [mask](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/calayer/1410861-mask) property which works similarly.  Set your image to the content property of your masking layer and set the masking layer as the mask for your background image layer.

Comment: Ty for the answer. I have tried the UIView mask property which works fine, but after I can't move the background with UIGestureRecognizer to have the same feature as photoshop (if I want to zoom the background ...).